# How to read mifare 4k card number on PAX A920

Tags: java, android, mifare

i'm developing an app that should run on PAX A920. I have imported the library to interface with the reader of the device but i can't read the MIFARE 4k card. The device dosen't detect it. I have also founded a demo developed for the device that contains all the functionality but still not detecting the card when open the contactless. The device doesn't support NFC. Has anyone worked with this device?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, do you have a link for the interface library and the demo for mifare? Thanks a lot of you can

Answer (score 1):

You should import pax device library. Than you will be able to read Mifare card with custom APDU commands like you have already did for public android mobile phone.

NFC is not provided out of the box in PAX devices unlike mobile android phones.

As you already know, PAX A920 is a kind of Point of Sale device and it has customized Android OS developed by PAX Global. So if you don't have device specific libraries, you should contact PAX support in order to get platform specific libraries.

Then you can read Mifare card from Contactless Card Reader Interface of device with sending custom APDU commands over a method provided by pax device library.

Comment: I have imported the pax device library. Do you know what is that command?

Comment: Then you should have library specific api documents. Try to search with APDU key and inspect document, you will find right method in order to send custom APDU commands.

Comment: Btw I am not sure I understood correctly. 
Are you looking for APDU Commands for reading mifare card? - It is global, not related for pax device. 
Or are you looking for the correct device api method to send your APDU command? I thought you need second one. If so you should check api docs, there should be some api methods that works for you.

Comment: I can read different type of card with the device but i can't read a mifare 4k card. The device dosen't detect the card. My question is how can i read the serial number of this card using the contacless reader of the PAX A920?

Comment: My mistake, then you should open an issue to pax ppm. I missed that you can read all mifare card except for 4k ones, because it's not detected by the contactless interface.

Comment: Thank you i appreciate it